# In Xcode, all objects on storyboard are now invisible but can still see the frames and constraints after update frames

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, storyboard

I was trying out stack views and selected update frames but now all my objects are missing.  The strange this is I can still see the frames and constraints!  How can I get my objects back?

[image: Last Viewcontroller on right]

Comment: Try unembedding the objects within the `stackview`, add `constraints` to those objects (height & width should do) and embed within `stackview` again

Answer (score 0):

your problem is your slack view is in front of everything I guess.

just, on the left white column, drap and drop one of the slack view and delete the other one.

For example it is like Photoshop, it is just a stack of layer so if you put something on the background, put it at the end of the stack.

EDIT: put a screen shot to see the change please